# Unipdf pdf creation- table rows with content spanning multiple pages has display issues

Tags: go, pdf

I'm using Unidoc's unipdf library to generate a pdf with multiple tables in it. 
When the content in a table cell is huge and needs to span over multiple pages, the pdf generated has the cells in the row scrambled, each cell goes over to a new page and no data is being displayed in the cell which has the huge data. 
And in the same scenario some times I see this process hangs and also starts eating up a lot of memory. 
Here are the screenshots of the same:
[Page1/cell1 - the cell spans the entire page but has only one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm95T.png)

[Page2/cell2 - with actual huge data, but no data being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyYcM.png)

[Page3/cell3 - the cell spans the entire page but has only one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GY1u.png)

The code snippet for doing the above:

```
func AddTableCell(c *ctx.Context, t *creator.Table, parag *creator.Paragraph, colSpan int, width float64, sides ...creator.CellBorderSide) {
  cell := t.MultiColCell(colSpan)
  for _, s := range sides {
    cell.SetBorder(s, creator.CellBorderStyleSingle, width)
  }
  cell.SetHorizontalAlignment(creator.CellHorizontalAlignmentLeft)
  cell.SetVerticalAlignment(creator.CellVerticalAlignmentMiddle)

  err := cell.SetContent(parag)
  c.NoError(err, "error setting cell content: %v", err)
}

func NewParagraph(c *creator.Creator, text string, font *pdfmodel.PdfFont, fontSize, lineHeight float64) *creator.Paragraph {
    parag := c.NewParagraph(text)
    parag.SetFont(font)
    parag.SetFontSize(fontSize)
    parag.SetColor(reportTextColor)
    parag.SetLineHeight(lineHeight)
    parag.SetEnableWrap(true)
    return parag
}
```

These are my two functions which help me draw the table
And here is how I use them:

```
for col := 0; col < len(rowVals); col++ {
    if col == 0 {
        AddTableCell(g.c, tb.Table, NewParagraph(g.Creator, rowVals[col], font, 10, 1.5),
            colSpans[col], tb.cellBorderWidth, creator.CellBorderSideAll)
    } else {
        AddTableCell(g.c, tb.Table, NewParagraph(g.Creator, rowVals[col], font, 10, 1.5),
            colSpans[col], tb.cellBorderWidth, creator.CellBorderSideTop, creator.CellBorderSideRight, creator.CellBorderSideBottom)
    }
    if g.c.HasErr() {
        return
    }
}
```

Using the same logic I'm able generate pdf for smaller piece of data but it breaks when the data is huge as shown in the screenshots above.
Does unidoc support handling data spanning multiple pages when embeded within tables? Or does it have some option/flag to enable it? What is it that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which you can use is

1. create [GO HTML template](https://gowebexamples.com/templates/) and render it.
2. Use [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf) to convert html to pdf.

I also faced similar issues where I was unable to generate a complex pdf and using wkhtmltopdf I was able to generate it.

ps: you can use `pdfg.AddPage` to add new page.

Comment: @AmitBhasuri thanks for this but I have other code in the project using unipdf and can't go away from it.

Answer (score 0):

The [newest release UniPDF v3.16.0](https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf/releases/tag/v3.16.0) (just released) adds  support for row-wrapping, and can be enabled via EnableRowWrap on the table:

```golang
t.EnableRowWrap(true)
```

We have verified that it works with your example posted above.

If you continue seeing large use of resources in the newest versions, please share with us. We have made some pretty big performance enhancements recently and will continue to improve it. Getting good bug reports is a great step towards that.

**Disclosure**: I am the original developer of UniPDF.

Comment: @GunnsteinHall thanks for the effort, appreciate it. But I tried this out using both the new version and EnableRowWrap flag, but it doesn't seem to work. The program still hangs and keeps consuming memory.

Comment: Make sure to use StyledParagraph instead of Paragraph.  The StyledParagraph supports page wrapping, whereas Paragraph only support single-page single-style text.  The inefficiency is likely because it never ends. Because the paragraph is larger than one page, the table tries to render it on the next. But it does not fit on the next one either. And so on.  Something we will look into avoiding or just returning an error in the future.